# How to Validate Multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

How can I validate multiple radio buttons. All these radio buttons generated dynamically.

```
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option1" value="1" id="ans_options1" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option1" value="2" id="ans_options2" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option1" value="3" id="ans_options3" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option1" value="4" id="ans_options4" />

<input type="radio"  name="answer_option2" value="5" id="ans_options5" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option2" value="6" id="ans_options6" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option2" value="7" id="ans_options7" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option2" value="8" id="ans_options8" />

<input type="radio"  name="answer_option3" value="9" id="ans_options9" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option3" value="10" id="ans_options10" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option3" value="11" id="ans_options11" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option3" value="12" id="ans_options12" />

<input type="radio"  name="answer_option4" value="13" id="ans_options13" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option4" value="14" id="ans_options14" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option4" value="15" id="ans_options15" />
<input type="radio"  name="answer_option4" value="16" id="ans_options16" />
```

Comment: Means you want to check if the radio button is selected?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/r9qR2/

Since each group has different name attribute so you have to do validation for each set of radio buttons.

```
if($('input[name="answer_option1"]:checked').length === 0) {
     alert('Please select one option');
}
```

If you have unlimited number of groups. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/r9qR2/2/

```
    //Make groups
    var names = []
    $('input:radio').each(function () {
        var rname = $(this).attr('name');
        if ($.inArray(rname, names) === -1) names.push(rname);
    });

    //do validation for each group
    $.each(names, function (i, name) {
        if ($('input[name="' + name + '"]:checked').length === 0) {
            console.log('Please check ' + name);
        }
    });
```

If you want to show just 1 error for all groups. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/r9qR2/224/

Comment: there are more than 50 groups.

Comment: hummm let me try something else :P

Answer (score 1):

try this new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Hgpa9/3/

```
$(document).on("click","#validate", function() { 
var names = [];

    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
        // Creates an array with the names of all the different checkbox group.
        names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
    });

    // Goes through all the names and make sure there's at least one checked.
    for (name in names) {
        var radio_buttons = $("input[name='" + name + "']");
        if (radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 0) {
            alert('none checked in ' + name);
        } 
        else {
            // If you need to use the result you can do so without
            // another (costly) jQuery selector call:
            var val = radio_buttons.val();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You select 1 radio button from first group. You don't select anything from other groups and this code is not valid.

Comment: try this new fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Hgpa9/3/ I have updated the code for multiple groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = []
$('input[name^="answer_option"]').each(function() {
    var rname = $(this).attr('name');
    if ($.inArray(rname, names) == -1) names.push(rname);
});

$.each(names, function (i, name) {
    if ($('input[name="' + name + '"]:checked').length == 0) {
        console.log('Please check ' + name);
    }
});
```

Comment: CSS3 not support IE8