# mutliple groups of radio button validation of this form which results in redirection to another page in jsp

Tags: forms, validation, jsp, radio-button

I wish if all the questions are answered then on click of submit button "Next" it should redirect to the next page else it should alert the user to "Answer all the questions" and must stay on the same page.
I've tried many methods but I've not been successful yet. so someone please help me out here for the logic for at least two questions ( two radio button groups). I'll do the rest.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>BFI Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcss.css">
</head>

<script>
    function ValRad(form)
    {

    }
</script>
<body>
    <h1>BFI Test</h1>
    <table border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Choose the appropriate option for the following:</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <form name="questionnaire" action="page2.jsp" method="POST" >
                        Question 1: I see myself as someone who is talkative.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 2: I see myself as someone who tends to find fault with others.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 3: I see myself as someone who does a thorough job.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 4: I see myself as someone who is depressed, blue.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 5: I see myself as someone who is original, comes up with new ideas.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 6: I see myself as someone who is reserved.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 7: I see myself as someone who is helpful and unselfish with others.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 8: I see myself as someone who can be somewhat careless.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 9: I see myself as someone who is relaxed, handles stress well.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 10: I see myself as someone who is curious about many different things.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 11: I see myself as someone who is full of energy.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question11" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question11" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question11" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question11" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question11" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 12: I see myself as someone who starts quarrels with others.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question12" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question12" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question12" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question12" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question12" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 13: I see myself as someone who is a reliable worker.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question13" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question13" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question13" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question13" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question13" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 14: I see myself as someone who can be tense.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question14" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question14" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question14" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question14" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question14" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 15: I see myself as someone who is ingenious, a deep thinker.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question15" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question15" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question15" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question15" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question15" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 16: I see myself as someone who generates a lot of enthusiasm.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question16" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question16" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question16" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question16" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question16" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 17: I see myself as someone who has a forgiving nature.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question17" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question17" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question17" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question17" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question17" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 18: I see myself as someone who tends to be disorganized.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question18" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question18" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question18" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question18" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question18" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 19: I see myself as someone who worries a lot.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question19" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question19" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question19" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question19" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question19" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 20: I see myself as someone who has an active imagination.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question20" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question20" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question20" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question20" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question20" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 21: I see myself as someone who tends to be quiet.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question21" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question21" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question21" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question21" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question21" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 22: I see myself as someone who is generally trusting.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question22" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question22" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question22" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question22" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question22" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 23: I see myself as someone who tends to be lazy.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question23" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question23" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question23" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question23" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question23" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 24: I see myself as someone who is emotionally stable, not easily upset.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question24" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question24" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question24" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question24" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question24" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 25: I see myself as someone who is inventive.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question25" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question25" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question25" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question25" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question25" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 26: I see myself as someone who has an assertive personality.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question26" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question26" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question26" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question26" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question26" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 27: I see myself as someone who can be cold and aloof.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question27" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question27" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question27" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question27" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question27" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 28: I see myself as someone who perseveres until the task is finished.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question28" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question28" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question28" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question28" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question28" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 29: I see myself as someone who can be moody.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question29" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question29" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question29" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question29" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question29" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 30: I see myself as someone who values artistic, aesthetic experiences.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question30" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question30" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question30" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question30" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question30" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 31: I see myself as someone who is sometimes shy, inhibited.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question31" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question31" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question31" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question31" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question31" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 32: I see myself as someone who is considerate and kind to almost everyone.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question32" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question32" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question32" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question32" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question32" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 33: I see myself as someone who does things efficiently.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question33" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question33" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question33" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question33" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question33" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 34: I see myself as someone who remains calm in tense situations.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question34" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question34" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question34" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question34" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question34" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 35: I see myself as someone who prefers work that is routine.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question35" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question35" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question35" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question35" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question35" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 36: I see myself as someone who is outgoing, sociable.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question36" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question36" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question36" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question36" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question36" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 37: I see myself as someone who is sometimes rude to others.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question37" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question37" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question37" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question37" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question37" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 38: I see myself as someone who makes plans and follows through with them.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question38" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question38" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question38" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question38" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question38" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 39: I see myself as someone who gets nervous easily.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question39" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question39" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question39" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question39" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question39" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        Question 40: I see myself as someone who likes to reflect, play with ideas.
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="question40" value="1" />Disagree strongly
                        <input type="radio" name="question40" value="2" />Disagree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question40" value="3" />Neither agree nor disagree
                        <input type="radio" name="question40" value="4" />Agree a little
                        <input type="radio" name="question40" value="5" />Agree strongly

                        <br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Next" name="go" name="Next2" onclick="ValRad(this.form)"/>
                    </form>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Validate Multiple radio buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609863/how-to-validate-multiple-radio-buttons)

Comment: it is almost same i tried but didn't work for me

Comment: What's the issue? Did you find any errors on console? Do the validation with minimal code.

Comment: it doesnt work actually when i try to click submit again without answering all ques it gives an NullPointer Exception instead of prompting the aleart message. Actually I'm using these values of Radio buttons in a Java Class for calculations too. @VinothKrishnan